# Equality operator (==) has no effect

Tags: python, equality-operator

I am currently following through a book (Python Crash Course), and have just been introduced to the '==' equality operator.

In the book, it shows setting a variable and checking whether it is equal to itself (using ==). See below.

Also tried numerical comparisons and having the same issue as outlined below.

```py
car = "bmw"
car == "bmw"
```

This is providing no output and PyCharm is telling me 'car == "bmw" has no effect. Book is telling me it should be responding "True" as I am checking the variable which I have literally JUST set.

Comment: PyCharm is saying this because you're not assigning the output to any variable. ```result = car == "bmw"``` will remove that warning

Comment: so the no output at this point is correct? apologies for the nooby question, just checking that there should definitely be no output at this point.

Comment: perfection. not explained in the book. thanks @KurtisStreutker

Comment: try to copy this code car = "bmw"
print (car == "bmw") #print is used to print values!?

Comment: Your book is probably not designed for using PyCharm - if you see `>>>` that means it's using the REPL, and you should be, too, if you're following along.

Comment: my bad, now I know. thanks @WayneWerner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
car = "bmw"
print(car == "bmw")
```

Or type your code directly in the console. Just running your script like that won’t produce anything, because you don’t do anything with the comparison.

Comment: Thanks. Not clarified in the book :)

Comment: A lot of those books start out by just typing/running scripts from the console instead of as a script.

Comment: I will move forward with the console only to avoid future issues. shame I asked the question, -4 is not ideal. Thanks Niels.

Comment: The downvoting is a bit of a sad thing, especially if your new and don’t know where to look/search for an answer to your problem. Don’t let it discourage you for future questions.

Comment: @Tempest agreed. This wasn't really an ideal question for SO, though over in [room 6](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python), the Python chat, it would be entirely acceptable :)

Comment: when I hit 20 rep ill swing on by. cheers @WayneWerner